# How to get the value from the return function and send it to the html element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have been working on a code to save the coordinates of bounding box over the image. I was able to retrieve the coordinates from the bounding box. But what I like to do is place them individually under each HTML element.

The image below shows the coordinates collected from the bounding box:

[image]

In the above image the coordinates are in a single line. But i would like to get those values individually.

HTML:

```
<div class="actions">

          <input type="button" id="btnView" value="Display areas" class="actionOn" />
          <input type="button" id="btnReset" value="Reset" class="actionOn" />
          <input type="button" id="btn_add" value="add areas" class="actionOn" />
 </div>
  <br>
 <div id="output" class='output'> </div>
 <input type= "hidden" id="x" name ="x" value="-">
 <input type= "hidden" id="y" name ="y" value="-">
 <input type= "hidden" id="w" name ="w" value="-">
 <input type= "hidden" id="h" name ="h" value="-">
```

Javascript:

```
  var selectionExists;

  function areaToString (area) {
    return (typeof area.id === "undefined" ? "" : (area.id + ": ")) + area.x + ':' + area.y  + ' ' + area.width + 'x' + area.height + '<br />'
  }



  function output (text) {
    $('#output').html(text);
  }

  // Log the quantity of selections
  function debugQtyAreas (event, id, areas) {
    console.log(areas.length + " areas", arguments);
  };

  // Display areas coordinates in a div
  function displayAreas (areas) {
    var text = "";
    $.each(areas, function (id, area) {
      text += areaToString(area);
    });
    output(text);
  };
```

From the above codes, the function DisplayAreas is used to display the coordinates of the bounding boxes in a single line using 'area.x', 'area.y', 'area.w' and 'area.h', but i would like to save each of the coordinated under each html elements like x, y , w and h.

i.e., from the image, when i press display areas button, the coordinates must be sent to the html elements x,y,w and h. and display as

X:
Y:
W:
H:

Can someone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.getElementById()` to access each of the inputs, and set its value to the corresponding property of the area.

```
  function displayAreas (areas) {
    var text = "";
    $.each(areas, function (id, area) {
      text += areaToString(area);
      document.getElementById("x").value = area.x;
      document.getElementById("y").value = area.y;
      document.getElementById("h").value = area.height;
      document.getElementById("w").value = area.width;
    });
    output(text);
  };
```